# Что делать, если я получаю ошибку 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' при попытке взять текст из span тега через BS4?

Tags: python, html, requests, bs4

Я пытаюсь спарсить данные о скидках с интернет магазина book24:

```
async def scraper_book24():
    data = {}

    url = "https://book24.ru/sales/"

    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    src = req.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

    blocks = soup.find_all("div", class_="sales-tabs-item__body")

    sales = []
    descriptions = []
    before = []
    links = []

    for block in blocks:
        try:
            sale = block.find("a", class_="sales-tabs-item__title-link")
            descript = block.find("div", class_="sales-tabs-item__desc")
            bef = block.find("span")
            link = sale.get("href")

        except:
            continue

        else:
            sales.append(sale.text)
            descriptions.append(descript.text)
            before.append(bef.text)
            links.append(link)

    data["sales"] = sales
    data["descriptions"] = descriptions
    data["before"] = before
    data["links"] = links

    return data
```

Но при запуске функции scraper_book24 я получаю ошибку

> File "C:\Users\belog\book_sales_bot\parsers.py", line 39, in
> scraper_book24
> before.append(bef.text) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

хотя я точно уверен, что класс тега введён правильно, да и тем более если я просто пытаюсь сделать print(bef.text), я получаю нужные мне данные. Также при выводе bef получаю нужный тег. Что я могу сделать с этой ошибкой?

Comment: Теперь python жалуется на это    `link = sale.get("href")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://book24.ru/sales/"
req = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "lxml")
blocks = soup.find_all("div", class_="sales-tabs-item__body")

data =[]
for block in blocks:
    sale = block.a.text
    descript = block.find("div", class_="sales-tabs-item__desc").text
    link = f'https://book24.ru{block.a["href"]}'
    try:
        bef = block.find("span").text
    except Exception:
        bef = "Нет акций"
    data.append({"sale": sale, "descript": descript, "bef": bef, "link": link})
print(data)

[{'sale': ' Выигрывают все! ', 'descript': 'Крутите колесо удачи и выигрывайте скидку!', 'bef': ' Акция действует до 31 декабря 2022 года ', 'link': 'https://book24.ru/sales/5709406/'}, .... {'sale': ' Бесплатная доставка по России ', 'descript': 'Многие покупатели ценят бесплатную доставку, поэтому в нашем интернет-магазине она есть!', 'bef': 'Нет акций', 'link': 'https://book24.ru/sales/205489/'}]
```